# Why does the jet come out perpendicular to the accretion disc?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies, accretion-disk

Why does the jet always come out perpendicular to the plane of the accretion disc around a black hole?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40624/why-are-relativistic-jets-perpendicular-to-the-accretion-disk/40918#40918
I answered this question on the astronomy site.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complicated question as it involves plasma physics. But the concept you're looking for is **magnetocentrifugal acceleration**
and concepts like Alfven surface etc. are involved.

What we will be looking at is the centrifugal-gravitational potential
\begin{equation}
\Phi(r,z) = - \frac{GM}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}} - \frac{GM}{2r_0^3}r^2
\end{equation}
where $r,z$ can be thought of as like cylindrical coordinates.
These coordinates are in reference to a system moving with the magnetic surface and $r_0$ is the base point where the accretion disk intersects the magnetic surface. Hence the second term in the potential is due to comoving with the surface: $\frac{1}{2} \Omega^2r^2$ (at supersonic speeds).
A magnetic surface is a surface of revolution due to the rotation of the poloidal magnetic field lines around the $z$-axis along which the magnetic flux is constant.
[image: Centrifugal gravitational potential]

The picture, taken from Prof. S. De Rijcke's course on "The Physics of Galaxies", shows the centrifugal-gravitational potential. The base point is a saddle point of this surface: all points to the right of the equipotential surface $(r_0,0)$ are points where the fluid elements will be slung away.
The equation for the equipotential surface through the base point in units $GM/r_0$ and $r$ in units $r_0$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}+\frac{r^2}{2} = \frac{3}{2}
\end{equation}
For $r \approx 1$ close to the base point we have that $z = \pm \sqrt{3}(r-1)$. Hence the equipotential surface makes an angle of 30 degrees with the vertical. If the magnetic surface has a larger angle then every element will be accelerated along the magnetic field lines. Since these field lines along with matter are confined to the magnetic surface this results in a collimated jet.